# LoadLibrary failed. Error 127

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, dll, visual-studio-2008

I have an executable C++ project (VS2008) which calls dll (VS2008). And that DLL also calls DLL (VS2012) which uses OpenCV. On the computer where Visual Studio is it works fine. But I have "LoadLibrary failed. Error 127" while trying to execute the same pack of files on another computer.

I've already checked the files with Dependency Walker and added all the DLLs missing.

Comment: It is a simple file-not-found error.  You just don't know which one.  Don't use Depends, use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  The trace shows the program searching for the DLL and not finding it.

Comment: @mats-petersson as I mentioned the files were added. In Dependency Walker everything was fine. The problem showed only in use because of the wrong version of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the version of the OpenCV dll's. Used vc10 instead of vc11 and it worked.